# Independent and Collaborative

Tags: syntactic-analysis, complex-sentences

I am trying to formulate the following sentence:

> The general framework is composed of two independent and collaborative modules

What I mean is that the two modules work independently but their end result is used in common to make a decision.

I find that this sentence is really contradicting itself. How can I make it more understandable?

Comment: "two independent **yet** collaborative modules"....

Comment: @Ste independent is not contra to collaborative, *and* is fine. In fact, it is *and* that is meant here.

Comment: Why should independent entities not collaborate? Dependence is not a prerequisite for collaboration at all. There's no contradiction.

Comment: *Modularity is the separation of an application in independent and collaborative modules. You use modules to encapsulate a set of concerns of your application and independently develop and deploy them to your applications. These modules are developed and maintained by multiple teams.* http://realworldsa.blogspot.in/2008/01/new-web-client-software-factory.html

Comment: @Kris I agree with both of your points but I read from the OP that it was the "and" that was the concern.  I think that "yet", whilst not contradictory, works here.

Comment: Why not just say what you mean?  Paraphrasing your own explanation,  how about "The general framework is composed of two modules; they are independent, but their results are combined to make a decision."

Comment: @Thruston you are right. I always complicate things. Your sentence is clear and simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general framework is composed of two modules; they are independent, but their results are combined to make a decision.